# How can I force the user to select dates that have passed when using the Date picker in the form API?

Tags: datetime

I need to use a pop up date picker from the Date module in the Form API.  It's displaying OK, but I want to restrict the user to only have the option of selecting dates that have passed, and not future dates.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
$form['fieldset_one']['date_field'] = array(
  '#weight' => '5',
  '#title' => t('Date of Birth'),
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
  '#date_year_range' => '-80:0',
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach:

Pass the JS options in `'#datepicker_options`'

```
$form['fieldset_one']['date_field'] = array(
  '#weight' => '5',
  '#title' => t('Date of Birth'),
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
  '#date_year_range' => '-80:0',
  '#datepicker_options' => array(
    'maxDate' => 0,
  ),
);
```

`maxDate => 0` should set the maximum date to today. -1 would set it to yesterday.

More info: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Answer (score 0):

They are talking about datepicker options here: [Customize days that can be clicked on a Calendar popup](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58968/customize-days-that-can-be-clicked-on-a-calendar-popup)

Apparently datepicker is quite versatile, with those options you can set max-date, min-date etc.