# Validate date selection in date picker

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I am using a javascript datepicker to allow users to select a date (which I have functioning in my form). What I don't know how to do is limit the dates that can be selected. Is there a way to do this using the datepicker instead of validating the form on submission?

Here is the code I am using to create the date selector:

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.datepicker');
drupal_add_js($path . '/providers/support/js/datepicker.js');
drupal_add_js(array('dateselector' => array('date_format' => $date_picker_format)), 'setting');
return array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => $current_value,
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('datefield')),
);
```

Am I missing an option somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit available dates you want `minDate`, `maxDate` and `beforeShowDay` [datepicker options](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/). `beforeShowData` is useful to limit allowed values programatically.

minDate and maxDate can be passed to js as:

```
drupal_add_js(array('dateselector' => array('date_format' => $date_picker_format, 'minDate' => '+1d')), 'setting');
```

.. and here's an example of beforeShowDay usage: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/60121/8437

btw, I'd recommend using [Date](https://drupal.org/project/date)'s date_popup form element in conjunction with [Date Restrictions](https://drupal.org/project/date_restrictions), for a variety of advanced restrictions.

Comment: Thanks! That really helped. The link provided helped as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see, how you initialize the datepicker (probably in */providers/support/js/datepicker.js file), but for this functionality you should use [maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) and [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) options of datepicker library.